# Continuance of environment

Tags: environments, amsthm

I am using an continuous example in my text, but I don't know how to do define the corresponding nice environment.

I am using the amsmath and ntheorem package and defined my own example-environment:

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
```

I am using the following documentclass:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
```

What I would like is a possibility to continue the example maybe like this

```
\begin{example} \label{ex1}
 This is an example.
\end{example}

Some text stands here. And then there is some space between this and the continued example. 
Further should the continued example not be intended but start at the beginning of the line.

\begin{continuance}[\ref{ex1}]
This is the continued example.
\end{continuance}

Some more text, which should follow after a little vertical space.
```

With the result:

Example 1.1 *This is an example.*

Some text stands here. And then there is some space between this and the continued example. 
Further should the continued example not be intended but start at the beginning of the line.

Continuance of Example 1.1 *This is the continued example.*

Some more text, which should follow after a little vertical space.

How can I define this continuance-environment?

Edit:
The problem now is that it looks like this

Example 1.1 *This is an example.*

Some text stands here. And then there is some space between this and the continued example. 
Further should the continued example not be intended but start at the beginning of the line.
[Here is an indention] Continuance of Example 1.1 *This is the continued example.*
Some more text, which should follow after a little vertical space.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `\newtheorem*`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem*{continuancex}{Continuance of Example \continuanceref}
\newenvironment{continuance}[1]
  {\newcommand\continuanceref{\ref{#1}}\continuancex}
  {\endcontinuancex}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Title}
\begin{example} \label{ex1}
 This is an example.
\end{example}

Some text stands here. And then there is some space between this and the continued example.
Further should the continued example not be intended but start at the beginning of the line.

\begin{continuance}{ex1}
This is the continued example.
\end{continuance}

Some more text, which should follow after a little vertical space.
\end{document}
```

In this way you'll be using the overall theorem style.

---

The following version works with `ntheorem`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newcommand{\continuanceref}{}
\newtheorem{continuancex}{Continuance of Example}
\renewcommand{\thecontinuancex}{\continuanceref}
\newenvironment{continuance}[1]
  {\renewcommand\continuanceref{\ref{#1}}\continuancex}
  {\endcontinuancex}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Title}
\begin{example} \label{ex1}
 This is an example.
\end{example}

Some text stands here. And then there is some space between this and the continued example.
Further should the continued example not be intended but start at the beginning of the line.

\begin{continuance}{ex1}
This is the continued example.
\end{continuance}

Some more text, which should follow after a little vertical space.
\end{document}
```

---

Here's a working version for `babel`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{ntheorem,refcount}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{continuancex}{Continuance of Example}
\renewcommand{\thecontinuancex}{\continuanceref}
\newenvironment{continuance}[1]
  {\edef\continuanceref{\getrefnumber{#1}}\begin{continuancex}}
  {\end{continuancex}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Title}
\begin{example}\label{ex1}
 This is an example.
\end{example}

Some text stands here. And then there is some space between this and the continued example.
Further should the continued example not be intended but start at the beginning of the line.

\begin{continuance}{ex1}
This is the continued example.
\end{continuance}

Some more text, which should follow after a little vertical space.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can this also be done with the package ntheorem?

Comment: Yes, I'll add the suitable version

Comment: Somehow this does not work when I also use the package babel with option english. Do you have any idea why that might be?

Comment: @Jana One more reason not to use `ntheorem` :)

Answer (score 6):

needs two LaTeX runs for correct references:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newenvironment{continuance}[1]
  {\par\bigskip\noindent\textbf{Continuence of Example #1. }\itshape}
  {\par}
\begin{document}

\begin{example} \label{ex1}
 This is an example.
\end{example}

Some text stands here. And then there is some space between this and the continued example. 
Further should the continued example not be intended but start at the beginning of the line.

\begin{continuance}{\ref{ex1}}
This is the continued example.
\end{continuance}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is almost perfect. How do I get 'This is the continued example.' to be also written emphasized?

Comment: use `\textsc{Continuence of Example \ref{#1}. }\itshape` in the definition

Comment: I am sorry but it doesn't work. I tried \newenvironment{continuance}[1]
  {\textsc{Continuence of Example \ref{#1}. }}
  {\itshape} and \newenvironment{continuance}[1]
  {\textsc{Continuence of Example \ref{#1}. }}
  \itshape.

Comment: Furthermore it is intended but there is no space above. I would like space above and no indention. How can I do that?

Comment: see my edited answer for `\itshape`. And _what_ is indented? Advance your example code in the question to a complete document that shows what's going wrong.

Comment: @Jana: see my edited answer