# End mark for unnumbered and continued examples

Tags: environments, theorems, amsthm

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{examplex}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem*{continuedex}{Example \continuedexref\space Continued}
\newtheorem*{example*}{Example}

\newenvironment{examcont}[1]
  {\newcommand{\continuedexref}{\ref*{#1}}\continuedex}
  {\endcontinuedex}

\newenvironment{example}
  {\pushQED{\qed}\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\triangle$}\examplex}
  {\popQED\endexamplex}

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
\begin{example}
\label{exa:foo}
  A numbered example.
\end{example}
\begin{examcont}{exa:foo}
  An example continued.
\end{examcont}
\begin{example*}
  An unnumbered example.
\end{example*}
\end{document}
```

This uses i) this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32394/9953) to add an end mark to the example environment and ii) this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68859/9953) to allow for for continued examples.

Currently I only have the end  triangle mark for the standard example environment. I want to have the end mark for both the continued example and the star (unnumbered) example.
How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: I guess you want something more than adding a `\hfill$\triangle$` to the end of your environment content?  As in, `\newenvironment{examcont}[1]
  {\newcommand{\continuedexref}{\ref*{#1}}\continuedex}
  {\hfill$\triangle$\endcontinuedex}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Sorry, I have just seen, that we have the same idea :D

Comment: @ChristianHupfer no problem at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symbol must be inserted at the end of the environment, 'flushed' right, so use `\hfill\myqedsymbol` where `\myqedsymbol` is a macro wrapper for the particular symbol (`\triangle` in this case)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{examplex}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem*{continuedex}{Example \continuedexref\space Continued}
\newtheorem*{example*}{Example}

\newcommand{\myqedsymbol}{\ensuremath{\triangle}}%

\newenvironment{examcont}[1]
  {\newcommand{\continuedexref}{\ref*{#1}}\continuedex}
  {\hfill\myqedsymbol\endcontinuedex}

\newenvironment{example}
  {\pushQED{\qed}\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\myqedsymbol}\examplex}
  {\popQED\endexamplex}

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
\begin{example}
\label{exa:foo}
  A numbered example.
\end{example}
\begin{examcont}{exa:foo}
  An example continued.
\end{examcont}
\begin{example*}
  An unnumbered example.
\end{example*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Version with qed mark for unnumbered example

The problem arises from the starred environment, so it's best to rename `example*` and define the `example*` as a wrapper environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{examplex}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem*{continuedex}{Example \continuedexref\space Continued}
\newtheorem*{examplestarred}{Example}

\newcommand{\myqedsymbol}{\ensuremath{\triangle}}%

\newenvironment{examcont}[1]{%
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\myqedsymbol}%
  \newcommand{\continuedexref}{\ref*{#1}}%
  \continuedex%
}{%
  \popQED%
  \endcontinuedex%
}%


\newenvironment{example}{%
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\myqedsymbol}%
  \examplex%
}{%
  \popQED%
  \endexamplex%
}%


\newenvironment{example*}{%
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\myqedsymbol}%
  \examplestarred%
}{%
  \popQED%
  \endexamplestarred%
}%

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
\begin{example}
\label{exa:foo}
  A numbered example.
\end{example}
\begin{examcont}{exa:foo}
  An example continued.
\end{examcont}
\begin{example*}
  An unnumbered example.
\end{example*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to load the extra `ragged2e` package?

Comment: @petobens: No, sorry, that was my first guess-- I will remove it

Comment: The unnumbered example doesn't have an end mark.

Comment: @Bernard: Correct, I forgot the look after that issue

Comment: @Bernard: Corrected the code

Comment: Why does the numbered example and the unnumbered example end the environment definition with `\popQED\endexample..` while the continued example ends with `\hfill\myqedsymbol`? And why isn't `\pushQED..` used in the continued example definition?

Comment: @petobens: Well, basically the whole `pushQED` stuff is not needed in my point of view, since the redefinition of the `\qedsymbol` occurs inside of a group, so it's safe outside. However, since the theorem environment is responsible for the typesetting, it is better to call the `\pushQED...\popQED` commands.

Comment: @petobens: I updated the code  -- all three environments use the `\pushQED...\popQED` macros now

Comment: @ChristianHupfer -- what the `\pushQED ...` code does is enable the environment to work with `amsmath` to use `\qedhere` to move the qed symbol up to the end of a display math line; otherwise the symbol would invariably end up on a separate line, and possibly break to a new page.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Thanks, I have not digged too deep into `amsmath` package, but after your explanation, I am glad, that I kept those macros ;-)

Comment: @petobens: You're welcome ;-)