# putting square in definitions

Tags: changes

I want to put `$\square$` on my definition. Similiar what we do on proof with command `\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}`.

Can I put this is my definitions? Could someone help me?

I tried renaming some commands but I got nothing.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Could you elaborate a bit on what you're wanting to do and what you've tried?  It's hard to tell what went wrong.

Comment: It sounds like you're after something like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205192/end-mark-for-unnumbered-and-continued-examples/205195#205195)?

Comment: Related: [Denoting the end of example/remark](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16453/14751).