# New theorem problem AMSTHM

Tags: amsthm

I have the Example environment as a new theorem environment but I need to break the example across the article. Ideally I would like to implement the following:

**Example 1**. *blah blah blah ...*

... more text form the article ...

**Example 1** *(continued).* *other blah blah blah*

I tried to define a newtheorem* environment `\newtheorem*{ex1}{Example 1}` but then I lose the bold part and the "continued" does not appear in parenthesis:

*Example 1*. *continued*

I was thinking the perhaps re-setting the counter manually before and after would solve it. But is this possible? Is there some better solution?

Comment: Does this question help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68830/continuance-of-environment

Comment: `thmtools` provides a convenient way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your particular case it might be easiest to do this:

```
    \newtheorem{example}{Example}
    \newtheorem{examplecontinued}[example]{\addtocounter{example}{-1}Example}
```

And then write

```
    \begin {example} 
    Lorem ipsum
    \end{example}

    \begin{examplecontinued}[continued]
    continued lorem ipsum
    \end{examplecontinued}
```

This will allow multiple breaks as well. If you want to, you can also define the `examplecontinued`-environment to  automatically display "(continued)" behind **"Example [counter] "**. How to do stuff like that is very well described in the [`amsthm`-documentation](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/required/amscls/doc/amsthdoc.pdf).